# Any official or semi-official continuation of Terminator - the Sarah Connor Chronicles TV-show?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

I've been re-watching the 2nd and final season of "Terminator - the Sarah Connor Chronicles" (I used to love that show) with great joy, and wonder if there were any official or semi-official continuation of the show - E.g. books, graphic-novels/comics, cartoons, audio-plays?  Has the plans/outlines for the never-made 3rd season been leaked?

Alternatively, are/were there any *really good* fanfiction that took up the threds from the show in a good way?

BTW, were there any books, graphic-novels etc. released while the show ran (that tied in to episodes)?

Comment: Not to mention operas, payrii, scrolls, stone tablets, sonnets and musicles </rondo>

Comment: Not an official continuation or fanfic, but [this interview](http://io9.com/5349566/sarah-connor-chronicles-season-3-would-have-featured-a-surprising-comeback) with the actor who played John Connor gives some insight into what series creator Josh Friedman had been planning. Also a little more info on their plans [here](http://www.tvguide.com/news/terminator-middleton-future-1006894/).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are no series, books, graphic novels or cartoons that are sequels to Terminator TSCC. Althrough I'm not sure about fanfictions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, good TSCC FanFiction. Well, there's 'I Love You Too' by King Steve, which serves as a very good season 3 substitute. It's long, dark and gritty, but very well written.

If you want something more lighthearted, there's the 'Wintertale' series by Troll99, which focuses on John and Cameron's relationship, but also has the heroes fighting bad guys. More family-oriented but still entertaining.

Answer (score -1):

There's no official continuation of TSCC however there is many Season 3 TSCC fanfiction some good, some bad.

I've also heard there is a cyborg novel series coming out that is heavily inspired by TSCC and Total Recall, but TSCC than Total Recall. Which is unfortunately another official continuation :(

Comment: The OP was looking for "official or semi-official". Fanfic is neither.

Comment: @Richard -- the OP does also say "Alternatively, are/were there any really good fanfiction that took up the threds from the show in a good way?" Still, this answer isn't very helpful since it mentions no specific examples of "good" fanfic.